# Use jQuery to ask if <div> has a background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use jQuery to check if `#page` has got a background image - `#page` could look like this:

```
<div id="page" style="background-image: url(xxx)"></div>
```

If it contains a background image, it should add a class to #page

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The default value for [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) is "none". So you can do it like this:

```
if ($('#page').css('background-image') != 'none') {
  alert('There is a background image');
}
```

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, this answer works as written even if the background image has been set via the `background` CSS property instead of the `background-image` CSS property. As [MDN notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), `background` is just a shorthand for setting other properties and a background image set through it *will* be correctly reflected in the value of the `background-image` property. By the way, +1. I note that this question languished without a correct answer for four years before you came along, and unambigously wrong answers accrued votes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var image = $('#page').css('background-image');
```

Should do the job.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, unlike steffanj's superior answer. -1

Comment: It does answer the question and should be the accepted answer.